# How to check that the string contains the number format in Java?

Tags: java, string

I am new to applet concept. I want to implement the one application. The applet have 2 text areas and one button. The first text area is the input(means it contains some text).Second Text area is empty.If you click on the button then the text in the first text area is parsed(here parsed means first text area text contains some text right? that text contains some number here that numbers will be removed and remaining text will be pasted in the second text area)
EX:
Text area1: 1. stack Overflow 2 Google 3 yahoo
after button click
Text area2: stack Overflow
            Google
            Yahoo

Here how to check the number in the string? and how to get the string up to the number.

```
public class parsetextdata extends Applet implements ActionListener{

    TextArea ta1,ta2;
    Button parse;
    public void init() { 
        ta1 = new TextArea();

        ta1.setText("1. Naresh Repalle 2. Lakshman Yalavarthy 3. Rajendra Batchu 4. Bhart Chand Yalavrthy ");
        add(ta1); 

        parse = new Button();
        parse.setLabel("parse");
        add(parse); 

        ta2 = new TextArea();    
        add(ta2);              

        parse.addActionListener(this);

      }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent button) {

        if(button.getSource() == parse)
        {
            String text = ta1.getText();        
            ta2.setText(text);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What about tagging it with string?

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

`text.replaceAll("[\\w]*[0-9.]+[\\w]*", "\n");`

It replaces all numeric characters and dots with a newline character, so if you put the result to a JTextArea, every name will be on a single line.

To get the Strings between the numbers, use the split() method.

```
String[] names = text.split("[\\w]*[0-9.]+[\\w]*");
```

The regex now also removes whitespaces between the numbers and the names. `String[] names` will contain the single names.

Comment: How to get the string in between the numbers (means 1. Stack overflow 2. Google how to get the stack overflow)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is simply to remove numbers (and whitespace as your examples do) you can simply use String.replaceAll like this:

```
ta2.setText(text.replaceAll("[0-9]+ ?", ""));
```

Comment: thanks. But i want to copy the string up to the number is find(means 1.stack overflow 2. Google after parsing in first line stack overflow and next line Google). Please how to do it

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand you. Do you mean you want to get the text between numbers in separate variables you can read? If so use `text.split("[0-9]");` This will give you an array of the Strings split on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
private static ArrayList <Character> getNumberRemoved(String string) {

    ArrayList <Character> list = new ArrayList <Character> ();
    char [] inString = string.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : inString)
    {
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <='9')
            continue;
        list.add(ch);
    }

    return list;
}
```

This will take O(n) time. basically walk through the characters and skip numbers.