# How to get the string between two numbers in Java?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check that the string contains the number format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753216/how-to-check-that-the-string-contains-the-number-format-in-java)

Lets say I have a string in the following format:

```
string1 = "1. Stack Overflow 2. Google 3. Reddit"
```

How do I pick out the the substrings between the numbers?

Comment: -1 for showing absolutely no effort.

Comment: @MattBall I second that.

Comment: Some people don't know the right way to ask for help some people are hostile in dealing with that. Both approaches are equally ignorant.

Answer (score 4):

try `String.split()`

```
String[] s = string.split("[0-9]+. ", String1);
```

would yield the array:

```
{"Stack overflow ", "Google"}
```

From which you could whichever string you want. To be extra nice, you might want to `trim()` the strings you yank out.

Comment: String1 is what you specify it to be in your question.

Answer (score 1):

loop through each character of `String` and see if its number then mark the start index and at the end mark the end index and do `substring`

**Methods to use **

- [`Character.isDigit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)
- [`String.toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)
- [`String.subsstring()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: We are not code factory. I in this answer have given more than code :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions and a capturing group:

```
String str = "1. Stack overflow 2. Google";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d\\. (.*?) \\d").matcher(str);

if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));    // Prints "Stack overflow"
```

---

[**IDEONE.com demo**](http://ideone.com/UEbgW)

Comment: In m.group(1) here "1" means what? How to get the google

Comment: `m.group(1)` returns the part of the match corresponding to `(.*?)`. If you want to google on this, search for *regular expression capturing groups* (Or read up for instance [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).)

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to match the above example would be

```
\d+\.\s(\D+)\d\.
```

Escaped for your convenience.

This will capture the text between the numbers (and dots) as matchgroup 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\. (\\D+)\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) 
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: Or in one line: str.replaceAll("^.*?\\d+\\. ", "").replaceAll(" \\d.*", "")

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to do your homework. You have made no effort. Have a look at this simple method. Implement it in your code and modify it so that it fits your problem.

```
public boolean isInteger( String input )  
    {  
       try  
       {  
          Integer.parseInt( input );  
          return true;  
       }  
       catch( Exception )  
       {  
          return false;  
       }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string split function works fine here too:

```
String test = "1. Stack overflow 2. Google";
String[] test2 = test.split("\\d\\.");
```

- `test2[0]` will be `" Stack overflow"`
- `test2[1]` will be `" Google"`

You can use `test2[0].trim()` to get rid of the extra spaces.